# Python - trying to import/open incorrectly formatted .xls file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I'm trying to write some Python code which needs to take data from an .xls file created by another application (outside of my control). I've tried using pandas and xlrd and neither are able to open the file, I get the error messages:
"Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually." using Pandas.
"Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n\t'" using xlrd

I think it has to do with the way the file is exported from the program that creates it. When opened directly through Excel, I get the error message "The file format and extension don't match". However, you can ignore this message and the file opens in a usable format and can be edited and all of the expected values are in the right cells etc. Interestingly, when I go to save the file in Excel, the default option that comes up is a webpage.

Currently I have a workaround in that I can just open the file in Excel, save it as a .csv then read it into Python as a csv. This does have to be done through Excel through, if I just change the file extension to .csv, the resulting file is garbage.

However, ideally I would like to avoid the user having to do anything manaully. Would be greatly appreciated if anyone has any suggestions of ways that this might be possible (i.e. can I 'open' the file in Excel and save it through Excel using Python commands?) or if there are any packages or comands I can use to open/fix badly formatted .xls files.

Cheers!

P.S. I'm pretty new to Python and only have experience in R otherwise so my current knowledge is quite limited, apologies in advance!

Comment: Do you use pd.read_excel ?

Comment: `you must specify an engine manually` Did you try doing that?

Comment: @DataSciRookie yeah I did

Comment: @JohnGordon have tried specifying all of the engines listed in the pandas user guide, and with xlrd I get the same issue as if I try to open it with xlrd, with the others an error say bad/not a zip file

Comment: `bad/not a zip file` well, it's _not_ a zip file, it's an xls file.  I don't understand this error.

Comment: @JohnGordon I beleive that .xlsx files are zipped but .xls files are not, so the engines that are looking for '.xlsx' files expect to find a zipped file. At least that's my understanding from a quick google

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

file_path = Path(filename)

df = pd.read_excel(file.read(), engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, get the same errors :( I don't think the issue was with the path, it was finding the correct file, just unable to open it due to the program that creates it doing something weird with the format of the excel file

Comment: yeah, but this time you specified the engine, so weird that does not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.